# DBMS access on files in linux

Tags: filesystems, memory, database

I've read that usually the records of a table (in a database) are organized in a file that is managed by the DBMS, not by the OS. That is, the DBMS decides the order of the blocks in a file, the internal structure of every block and when to save a page (from RAM) in its correspondent block. Is this also possible in Linux ?

Can a DBMS also decide to put the blocks of a file contiguously in hard disk or this is managed exclusively by the OS ?

Thanks

Comment: When I first used Oracle (1995) it had a (raw?) mode where it totally bypassed the file system (at least on windows). All data was stored on an unformatted (by the OS) partition which the DBMS managed. It was fast, but introduced overhead since you could not perform backup/restore other than by using the DBMS tools.

Answer (score 0):

1) Many databases *do* manage the file(s) containing their data in Linux.

2) Writing to contiguous blocks is a file system function, and much more critical to Windows than Linux. It *could* be done in the application, but I am not aware of a database which does.

SSDs make it moot, anyway, because the 'blocks' an OS writes to, do not correspond to sequential cells of memory in an SSD; there's an abstraction layer which is managed by the firmware inside the drive.